# Bootstrap Affix conflicting CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to affix the following code to the top of the page, below the nav so it is always visible.

```
<div class="col-lg-5 nopadd affix">
    <h3>Project One</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>
</div>
```

However when I add the bootstrap `.affix` it makes it ignore the `col-lg-5` class that has been applied.

Here is the code I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/P9d5k/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/P9d5k/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9d5k/3/)

I just add a 100% width div with the affix class and inside a .container with your grid inside

```
<div class="affix" style="width:100%;z-index:2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
             <h3>Project One</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae. Sed dui lorem, adipiscing in adipiscing et, interdum nec metus. Mauris ultricies, justo eu convallis placerat, felis enim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```